# Running powershell scripts specific to a VCenter when connected to may VCenters

Tags: powershell-2.0, vmware, powercli

Assuming that i'm connected to more than one VCenters, how do i use the get-vm command for a specific VCenter and not for all?

Eg: im connected to server1 and server2

i want to get the list of all VMs in server 1 and not server 2.

Comment: maybe `get-vm -server server1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-Server` switch for `Get-VM`. i.e.

```
$server1 = Connect-VIServer server1
$server2 = Connect-VIServer server2
Get-VM -Server $server1
Get-VM -Server $server2
```